# Cucumber steps is not shown at allure report as expected

Tags: java, cucumber, rest-assured, allure

all I'm creating API tests using the following tools:

1. TestNG
2. Cucumber
3. Allure report
4. Rest assured

tests execution can be done using testNG suites.

after the test is executed I'm creating the allure report using the maven command

```
mvn allure:report
```

but the allure steps are not generated in the report as expected please see the following screen-shot

[image]

while my goal is to have this reporting structure:

[image]

here is test code example

```
@Test
@CucumberOptions (features="src/main/java/com/abc/tests/caseTest/caseTest.feature"
        ,glue={"com.tests.caseTest"}
        ,plugin={"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports"
        , "html:target/cucumber-html-reports"
        ,"rerun:target/failed_scenarios.txt"}
)
public class CaseTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

}
```

- 

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <rest-assured.version>5.1.1</rest-assured.version>
    <allure.testng.version>2.19.0</allure.testng.version>
    <allure.rest-assured.version>2.19.0</allure.rest-assured.version>
    <jackson.version>2.12.3</jackson.version>
    <json.version>20210307</json.version>
    <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.5.1</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <aspectj.version>1.9.7</aspectj.version>
    <assertj-core.version>3.23.1</assertj-core.version>
    <elasticsearch-client.version>7.17.0</elasticsearch-client.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin-version>3.0.0-M5</maven-surefire-plugin-version>
    <cucumber.version>7.9.0</cucumber.version>
    <cucumber-testng.version>7.9.0</cucumber-testng.version>
    <allure-cucumber-jvm.version>2.20.0</allure-cucumber-jvm.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
      <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
      <version>${assertj-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
      <artifactId>allure-rest-assured</artifactId>
      <version>${allure.rest-assured.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.automatedowl</groupId>
      <artifactId>allure-environment-writer</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
      <version>${cucumber-testng.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
      <artifactId>allure-cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
      <version>${allure-cucumber-jvm.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
      <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
      <version>${allure.testng.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>${json.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.24</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>


  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
          <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <buildDirectory>${project.basedir}</buildDirectory>
        </configuration>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin> <!-- This plugin is very important for Allure attachments and steps -->
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-surefire-plugin-version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>TestNG.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
          <argLine>
            -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
            -Dcucumber.options="--plugin io.qameta.allure.cucumber4jvm.AllureCucumber4Jvm"
          </argLine>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

- 

```
Feature: Case creation update and pemissions


  Scenario: create new case from Search
    Given User get list of ecomms
    When User create case using 3 ecomms from the list
    Then Response body should be valid with response code 200
    And Case should include 3 ecomms taken from search api
```

Answer (score 1):

I handle it by work arround, at steps definition class I added one allure Step annotation. so for example:

if the step definition look like:

```
@When("User type user name {string}")
public void typeUserName(String userName) {
}
```

now it looks like this

```
@When("User type user name {string}")
@Step("When User type user name {userName}")
public void typeUserName(String userName) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In one of the projects I use the following depedencies and plugins and everything works good.

```
<dependencies>
  <!--Cucumber Dependencies-->  
    <dependency>
       <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
       <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
       <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  
  <!--Selenium Dependency-->
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
       <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
       <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
 
  <!--Cucumber TestNG Dependency-->
    <dependency>
       <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
       <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
       <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
 
  <!--Hamcrest Dependency-->
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
       <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
       <version>2.2</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
     
  <!--Allure Cucumber Dependency-->   
      <dependency>
         <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
         <artifactId>allure-cucumber5-jvm</artifactId>
         <version>${allure.cucumber5.version}</version>
    </dependency>  
</dependencies>
```

```
<build>
    <plugins>   
      <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source> 
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target> 
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
      
     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                 <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>TestNG.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    -Dcucumber.options="--plugin io.qameta.allure.cucumber5jvm.AllureCucumber5Jvm"
                </argLine>
                         
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
         
         <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>${allure.maven.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportVersion>${allure.version}</reportVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
      </plugins>      
   </build>
```

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <selenium.version>3.141.59</selenium.version>
    <cucumber.version>5.7.0</cucumber.version>
    <testng.version>7.4.0</testng.version>
    <allure.cucumber5.version>2.14.0</allure.cucumber5.version>
    <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.5.1</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
    <maven.surefire.plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</maven.surefire.plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <aspectj.version>1.9.6</aspectj.version>
    <allure.maven.version>2.10.0</allure.maven.version>
  </properties>
```

Comment: can you please add the depndencies versions

Comment: updated my answer above